# GetPixel via DirectX 11 efficient implementation

Tags: c++, gdi, directx-11

I have this function that get a Pixel color from the screen with GDI+ API:

```
 RGBTRIPLE GetPixelColorGDI(int x, int y)
    {
        RGBTRIPLE rgb;
        HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    
        COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    
        rgb.rgbtRed = GetRValue(color);
        rgb.rgbtGreen = GetGValue(color);
        rgb.rgbtBlue = GetBValue(color);
    
        return rgb;
    }
```

the function works perfectly but it is too slow.

For this reason I like to try to implement the equivalent in DirectX 11 (I don't have a good experience in DirectX in general) and please excuse me if it is incorrect, this in my first attempt:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get pixel color from screen (24 bit) via DirextX 11
/// </summary>
/// <param name="X"></param>
/// <param name="Y"></param>
/// <param name="swapchainDescription"></param>

RGBTRIPLE GetPixelColorDX11(int X, int Y, IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain)
{
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;
    HRESULT hr = 0;
    using Texture2D = ID3D11Texture2D*;
    IDXGIResource* backbufferptr = nullptr;
    ID3D11Resource* SourceResource = nullptr;
    Texture2D DestResource = nullptr;
    ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedSubresource;

    hr = pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(IDXGIResource), (void**)&backbufferptr);
    if (hr < 0) {
        return;
    }
    hr = backbufferptr->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)&SourceResource);
    if (hr < 0) {
        return;
    }
    hr = pSwapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (void**)&device);
    if (hr < 0) {
        return;
    }
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC desc;
    hr = pSwapChain->GetDesc(&desc);
    if (hr < 0) {
        return;
    }

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TextureDesciption = { };
    TextureDesciption.Format = desc.BufferDesc.Format;
    TextureDesciption.Width = desc.BufferDesc.Width;
    TextureDesciption.Height = desc.BufferDesc.Height;
    TextureDesciption.MipLevels = 1;
    TextureDesciption.ArraySize = 1;
    TextureDesciption.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    TextureDesciption.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    TextureDesciption.BindFlags = 0;
    TextureDesciption.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    TextureDesciption.MiscFlags = 0;
    hr = device->CreateTexture2D(&TextureDesciption, nullptr, &DestResource);
    if (hr < 0) {
        return;
    }

    device->GetImmediateContext(&context);
    if (!context) {
        return;
    }

    context->CopyResource(DestResource, SourceResource);

    context->Map(DestResource, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &MappedSubresource);

    COLORREF* pPixels = (COLORREF*)MappedSubresource.pData;

    rgb.rgbtRed = (pPixels[0] >> 16) & 0xff;
    rgb.rgbtGreen = (pPixels[0] >> 8) & 0xff;
    rgb.rgbtBlue = pPixels[0] & 0xff;

    return rgb;
}
```

In this code is missing where I can set in X and Y coordinate in pixel because I don't known how to do it.

Apart this I don't sure if this way is enough efficient to make this more faster then the GDI++
`GetPixel` version.

The idea is (I don't sure if is possible) is select only one pixel (x, y) on source texture and read the color on "pPixels[0]"

**Update**

I explain better why I need and why.

My hooked DLL hook the DX11 "present" and draw a rectangle using shader that work as "placeholder" on a game menu.

Drawing phase is very fast becouse use DX11 and there no any FPS drop.

To do it I use a library called "imgui".

Before draw the rectangle I need to known in what position I need to place the rectangle and this depend by the result of the actual GetPixelColorGDI that is slow.

The user press a arrow key to move the rectangle on another position.

I call "GetPixelColorGDI" from 1 to 11 times for single screen.

If the next slot is filled I call GetPixelColorGDI only one time, but if the next 10 slots are empty I need to call GetPixelColorGDI 10 times.

So best solution can be create GetPixelColorDX11 like this:

```
RGBTRIPLE GetPixelColorDX11(int X, int Y, IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain)
```

and this overloald:

```
struct COORDINATE
{
 int x;
  int y;
 }
 RGBTRIPLE[] GetPixelColorDX11(COORDINATE[] Pixel , IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain)
```

so this can cover all cases.

here my function that I use to initialize DirectX to draw the rectangles:

```
bool InitDirectX(IDXGISwapChain* pChain)
{
    // Get swapchain
    pSwapchain = pChain;

    // Get device and context
    HRESULT hr = pSwapchain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (PVOID*)&pDevice);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get device from swapchain" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&pContext);

    // Get window from swapchain description
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapchainDescription;
    pSwapchain->GetDesc(&swapchainDescription);
    hWindow = swapchainDescription.OutputWindow;

    // Use SetWindowLongPtr to modify window behaviour and get input
    wndProcHandlerOriginal = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(hWindow, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)hWndProc);

    std::cout << "Successfully initialised DirectX - resolution " << swapchainDescription.BufferDesc.Width << "x" << swapchainDescription.BufferDesc.Height << std::endl;

    // Update the screen resolution multiplier
    UpdateResolutionMultiplier(swapchainDescription.BufferDesc.Width, swapchainDescription.BufferDesc.Height);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you're not doing this in a D3D11 application why not just use the GDI method? The slowness FWIW has to do with bringing data back from the GPU in general. So you really can't get fully around it.

Comment: I have created a hooked DLL that use DirectX 11 do draw rectangles on a game and others and I have hook the "present" method. Theorically  The DLL is complete but GetPixel is slow. I need a more fast way. I should have done it from the start but I had no experience in DX11 (and even now I don't have much)

Comment: Getting pixels one by one will always be "slow". Why do you need individual pixels in the first place?

Comment: If you're drawing rectangles have you considered just using a shader? It might be able to do everything you need. But without knowing why you're calling `GetPixel` that's going to be hard to say.

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail.

Comment: If just need to call GetPixel like ~11 times per key press, why performance is an issue with GDI?

Comment: because when I call GetPixel 11 times the game stop for 0.2 seconds. and when I press a arrow key fast the game lose fluidity.

Comment: For DirectX just allocate everything you can beforehand (not for each call), especially the staging texture. The staging texture should only be 1x1 (you may need to align on 2/4/8 boundary if you get error but you just need a small one). Try to only call CopySubresourceRegion at each GetPixel call (keep all device etc. references alive and recreate them if you get an error like they have been destroyed or something like screen change/reset). Other than that, if you don't own the process, it's difficult to do better in the general case

Comment: I have attach the funciton that I use to init directx to draw the rectangles. I have already "pContext", "swapchainDescription" and "pDevice"  . Can be a good idea pass all of these parameters in my "GetPixelColorDX11" ? what you think ?

Comment: Your GetPixelColorDX11 function should basically only do (CopySubresourceRegion+Map+return pixel). The rest (including staging texture creation) should be done once (and redone if context/device/swapchain are dead and need to be gotten again)